# Why does model theory usually study complete theories?

Tags: model-theory

Is it just a matter of complete theories being the simpler ones to understand? Do the methods of model theory essentially require that the theories be complete.

It seems that even for a complete theory, it can be very difficult to classify and understand its models, and I guess the feeling is that things would even harder for incomplete theories and maybe the methods of model theory would not work/work as well.

Comment: Models of a theory $T$ are models of its completions. So we can classify the models by their theories, and understand the models of $T$ by models and behaviours of the various completions of $T$.